# Hide Android/data/package_name/ folder to restrict user to access it directly from internal storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, validation

in my app's storage structure, Data are being stored inside Android/data/package_name/file_folder
I want to restrict the user to access this files directly from file explorer in Android Kotlin/Java.
kindly suggest something except renaming files with prefix of "."(Dot) that's not permanent solution.

i couldn't get any proper solution to implement it correctly.

Comment: File explorer apps on Android 11+ devices have no access to that app specific directory.

Comment: any other way to hide all files stored in package folder from user ?

Comment: ???? And what is a package folder? And why would you hide is nobody has access?

Answer (score 0):

The package folder is always available to android users as it falls into the root folder **storage/emulated/0/**.
Folder **Android** and it's folders **data, media, obb** can be accessible to all apps and users when the request to have it e.g

```
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File:

//File permissions enabled in Android manifest
final File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/your.app.package/files/img.jpg");

if(imagePath.exists()){
    //File exists and can be read
} else {
    //File doesn't exist or folder ain't present 
}
```

You may consider:

**ENCRYPTION OF FILES IN THAT FOLDER MAYBE**

Encrypt files in that folder with keys that your app has.

Comment: but i want to restrict user to access this file ?
can we do with password protection to this package folder programmatically ?

Comment: No you can't but you can password protect all the files in that folder